# Not getting response calculation from express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

just tell me what is missing in my code?

here is my html code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> -->
    <style media="screen">
      body {background-color: powderblue;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="n1" placeholder="First Number">
      <input type="text" name="n2" placeholder="Second Number">
      <button type="button" name="button">Calculate</button>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Express js code:-

```
// jshint esversion:6

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
app.post("/", function(req, res){
  var num1 = Number(req.body.n1);
  var num2 = Number(req.body.n2);
  var result = num1 + num2;
  res.send("The result is: " + result)
});
app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("App is running on port 3000");
});
```

I have imported body-parser. But still not working.
I want to get output as the Result on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either

```html
<button>Calculate</button>
```

(without the `type` attribute), or use

```html
<input type="submit" value="Calculate"/>
```

Your `<button type="button">` does not trigger a submission of the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" name="button">Calculate</button>
```

to

```
<button type="submit" name="button">Calculate</button>
```

work for me

Comment: req.body this can be replaced by https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/querystring.html but is not a response just comment ;)

Comment: It worked for me I just missed that type in button.